# Unable to find elements on Amazon page using beautiful soup 4

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

Hello I am trying to determine the price of an Amazon item using beautiful soup 4 package on python but I keep getting a none type object error so it cannot find the price

I have tried switching up the span and id element to see if that might be causing the issue but it does not change anything

```
my python code:
amazon_price_checker('https://www.amazon.com/Merax-Finiss-Aluminum-Mountain-    
Brakes/dp/B016A59WPM')
def amazon_price_checker(amazon_link):
   print(amazon_link)
   headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) \
    AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228.0 \
    Safari/537.36',
    }
   res = requests.get(amazon_link, headers=headers)
   res.raise_for_status()
   soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'html.parser')
   price = soup.find("span", {"id": "priceblock_ourprice"}).get_text()
   print(price)

html code on website:
<span id="priceblock_ourprice" class="a-size-medium a-color-price 
priceBlockBuyingPriceString">$239.99</span>
```

I expect the output to be 239.99 but get this error

```
https://www.amazon.com/Merax-Finiss-Aluminum-Mountain-Brakes/dp/B016A59WPM
Traceback (most recent call last):

price = soup.find("span", {"id": "priceblock_ourprice"}).get_text()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_text'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like a bug with `html.parser` (or maybe the raw html is invalid). Using `lxml` or `html5lib` instead works

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'lxml')
```

prints out

```
$239.99
```

Comment: @TawhidK When you write "html.parser" you are telling beautifulsoup to use pythons builtin html parser which is slow and not very good. Using lxml just tells python to use a different, better parser.